# Shopping cart rules

Tags: cart, rules, shopping

We offer an automatic discount of 10% over $300, no coupon code needed.  However when we run another promotion, for instance, 15% using a coupon code, that discount is being added on to the automatic 10% discount, giving the customer a 25% discount.  Is there a way to set the 15% promotion to discount the subtotal only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort orders if you want some rule to precede others or you can mark the first rule found is used only, i think you must use the order field too to say wich one will be first validated